# Spring security anotation not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've tried and tried, but seems like i'm unable to make the spring security annotation work.  I've refer to alot of sites.. and i cant seems to see what's wrong with my code. any help will be much appreciated

Here is spring security xml

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.css" access="permitAll" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.js" access="permitAll" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('LANDING')" />
  <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/landing" authentication-failure-url="/login" authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccesHandler" />
  <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</security:http>
```

here is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter> 
  <filter-name>XSSFilter</filter-name> 
  <filter-class>simptex.my.core.security.filter.XSSFilter</filter-class> 
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping> 
  <filter-name>XSSFilter</filter-name> 
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/application-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

here is a sample of java code

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_TELLER')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/urlxxxx" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String controlerMethod(HttpServletRequest req, HttpSession session) {


    return "urlxxxx";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think you're using the wrong expression. According to the Spring documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html), I don't see a `hasAuthority()` expression. There is however a `hasRole()` expression. So in your case I believe you need to change the annotation to  `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_TELLER')")`.

Secondly, the Spring Documentation states:

> To use hasPermission() expressions, you have to explicitly configure a PermissionEvaluator in your application context

So in your security XML configuration use the following bean declaration:

```
<bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" />
```

And then update your `security:global-method-security` definition to look something like:

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
     <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</security:global-method-security>
```

That should be enough to get the default Spring Security annotations running out of the box.